# Do we need to add security.yml on heroku for deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have developed application in ROR,

My security.yml file have following entries,

```
admin_name: *****
admin_email: user@example.com
admin_password: *****
domain_name: ******
secret_key_base: *****
email_provider_username: ****
email_provider_password: ******
```

How to add these entries on heroku configration ?

Answer (score 1):

I would read sensitive data from the environment.

Change your yaml files to something like this:

```
admin_name: <%= ENV['ADMIN_NAME'] %>
```

Then set the config with the Heroku cmd:

```
$ heroku config:set ADMIN_NAME=your_admin_name
```

Read the [Heroku docs about config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).